# SQLite: how do I update the primary key column in a Table after onClick?

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

Can I use the primary key column as an incremental counter?  The default value should be 1.  Every time the user clicks the Save button I'd like the table column to update by +1.  I will then push the individual row value to a CardView in a RecyclerView.  If so, should I use INSERT or UPDATE or ContentValues to add another row?

Or should I set up a second column for the incrementing values and push that data to the CardViews and leave the primary key column alone?

Activity file:

```
...
public void onClickSave(View v) {
...
int cardnum = 0;
helper.insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT(cardnum);
```

DBContract file:

```
...
public static abstract class DBEntry implements BaseColumns {

    // Strings for TOTALCOUNT TABLE
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT = "totalcount";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID = "_id";
}
```

DBHelper file:

```
...
public void insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT(int cardnum) {

    // Get a reference to a writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    // Insert values into the Table
    ? 

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    // Close the DB
    if(db.isOpen())
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Updating a PK is no different than updating any other column; *any enforced constraints must be honored* but it is not otherwise 'special'. However, doing so is very .. unconventional, and probably broken for a counter as then the PK could not be guaranteed to be a [useful] **Key**. It would be much better to add an appropriately named 'counter' column. (And no, such counter is not automatic.) The choice of adding a row (a journaled/stage database schema) is different than updating a column (a state-view database schema) and depends on use-case and multiplicity requirements.

Comment: Ok so if I add a second column then I will have to write +1 for each column for the insert?  Or can I just insert NULL into the PK column and it will  increment +1 above the largest previous value for PK?

Comment: If a *new* record is created, and the ID is *not* specified (as opposed to being specified as NULL), and the PK is of the magic auto-increment definition, then SQLite will insert 'some unique value'. It is *not* strictly guaranteed to be "one more" - esp. across database implementations, and subtle quirks; ie. SQLite can fill in values or skip values on transactions - and assuming such has led to some subtle bugs. But the question still remains: is the goal to *have* multiple records (*regardless* of the PK value)?

Comment: I'd rather not use autoincrement as SQLite warns will cause load on CPU and memory.  Based on your comment, it would be best to use INSERT and increment both columns each by +1?

Comment: What is the point of updating the [Primary Key, which must be Unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)? Do the other values in the row depend on the number of clicks and *only* the number of clicks?

Comment: No I just want a column that adds a row after each click with a +1, and a starting value of 1.  And then be able to access the value of the row in my Adapter file of the RecyclerView for each CardView (also created by the click).  I want to give the CardView a number tha corresponds to the row value that occurs at each click.

Comment: My thought would be to use the PK column to uniquely identify the row for the RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: Yes, a PK identifies a row. An increasing counter is an aspect of a row.

Comment: OK I will use two columns.  I'm not clear about the best way to increment the PK though on each click.  Am I good to increment the PK by +1?

Comment: Why do you *want/need* to increase the PK? A PK must be *unique*, which makes it ill suited to a counter. Think of it as Name for a specific person, and a count (of actions) as an Age. A person gets older each year. Yet names rarely, if ever, change.

Comment: I thought the ID has to increase for each row so that each CardView can be associated with a different (increasing) number.  Is that not the case?

Comment: PK's *must* be unique such that they can identify the row. It doesn't matter how this is. **Adding a new row is different than updating data related to a row.**

Comment: So I just declare the PK column name and then leave it alone?  And then just use INSERT or ContentValues for the second counter column to add rows?

Comment: If lacking a useful value to put in a PK, just use an auto-increment PK: the PK value chosen is just an identity with no other meaning. Just be aware this is *not* an 'sequence number' column. Usually a non-compound PK will never be an ordering column.

Comment: Well I'm looking for an ordering column for the RecyclerView's Adapter.  Is there any other way to do it without auto-increment so as to avoid the heavier load on CPU and memory?